# ACF Querying relationship field with True / False

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a post type called **rto_providers** which has a relationship field to select which courses they provide from another post type called **courses**. A list of providers will be showing on specific course pages according to the relationship selection. In case if I want to deactivate a specific provider I thought of using True/False function on **rto_providers** so that provider will be temporary removed from the list.

I tried following code which is in Single course page template. But I’m getting all the providers which has a **true** value.

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

        $rto_providers = get_posts(array(
          'post_type' => 'rto_providers',
          'meta_query' => array(
            array(
              'key' => 'courses_offered',
              'value' => '"' . get_the_ID() . '"',
              'compare' => 'LIKE',
              'key' => 'status',
              'compare' => '==',
              'value' => '1'
            )
          )
        ));
        ?>

        <?php if( $rto_providers ): ?>
          <?php foreach( $rto_providers as $rto_provider ): ?>
            <div class="row bordered-row random">
              <div class="col-md-2 providers-list">
                <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $rto_provider->ID ); ?>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-8">
                <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $rto_provider->ID ); ?>">
                  <?php echo get_the_title( $rto_provider->ID ); ?>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-2">
                <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $rto_provider->ID ); ?>" class="btn btn-base">
                  Visit Page
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
```

how to filter the results with posts which only has true value?

**Ex:** 
I have three providers called P1,P2 and P3, and I have a course called C1. 
Only P1 and P2 provides C1. C1 should display only P1 and P2's names. Instead my code shows all P1 2 and 3. Because default True/False value is '1' on all providers.

Comment: I'm not clear on what you are trying to get - you have a true/false option on providers, and your query is returning all providers that are set to true. That sounds like its doing what it should, so what are you trying to get?

Comment: I know it's abit confusing. Provided an example. Hope you can have a much clear idea now?

Comment: Sorry, I'm still a bit confused! I understand what you are trying to do, but I'm not sure of how your CPT / ACF is set up... the relationship between the course & provider is in the Provider CPT `rto_providers`, yes? And `courses_offered` is the relationship field in the `rto_providers` CPT? So in each `rto_providers` post, it has a list of the courses that provider gives? So where does your true/false setting come in - what is it called, and how is it being included in your query?